# Count number of figures, tables and citations in report class

Tags: floats, counters, report

I'm using report documentclass and trying to use `totcount` for counting figures, tables and references, but there are two problems:

1. Figures and tables counters are reset for each chapter, so `\total{figure}` and `\total{table}` is displaying 0. How to find the total count of figures and tables throughout the document?
2. A solution for counting references given in `totcount` documentation

   ```
   \newtotcounter{citesnum}
   \def\oldcite{} \let\oldcite=\cite
   \def\cite{\stepcounter{citesnum}\oldcite}
   ```

   isn't working for me since I have several `\cite{}` commands for single reverence. Is there a way to work around this one as well?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use auxiliary counters for figures and tables and patch `\chapter` (using the `etoolbox` package, for example) to add the value `\value{figure}` (resp. \value{table}) to the respective auxiliary counter; a similar procedure can be applied for tables; then, at the end of the document this operation is once again performed and the result is written to the `.aux` file in two macros that hold the total values:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{totfigures}
\newcounter{tottables}

\providecommand\totfig{} 
\providecommand\tottab{}

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
  \addtocounter{totfigures}{\value{figure}}%
  \addtocounter{tottables}{\value{table}}%
  \immediate\write\@mainaux{%
    \string\gdef\string\totfig{\number\value{totfigures}}%
    \string\gdef\string\tottab{\number\value{tottables}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\pretocmd{\chapter}{\addtocounter{totfigures}{\value{figure}}\setcounter{figure}{0}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\chapter}{\addtocounter{tottables}{\value{table}}\setcounter{table}{0}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
There are \totfig\ figures and \tottab\ tables in this document.
\begin{figure}FA\caption{test FA}\end{figure}
\begin{table}TA\caption{test TA}\end{table}
\begin{figure}FB\caption{test FB}\end{figure}

\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\begin{figure}FC\caption{test FC}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}FD\caption{test FD}\end{figure}
\begin{table}TB\caption{test TB}\end{table}
\begin{figure}FE\caption{test FE}\end{figure}

\chapter{Test Chapter Three}
\begin{table}TC\caption{test TC}\end{table}
\begin{figure}FF\caption{test FF}\end{figure}
\begin{table}TD\caption{test TD}\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You need to run at least twice the code.

After testing, I noticed that, for some reason, if some chapter does not contain any figures, the counting is wrong. By appending `\setcounter{figure}{0}` to the `\pretocmd` code, I get the correct results. My guess is that the figure counter holds the value of the previous chapter, when no figures have been defined in the current chapter. I may be wrong though. In any case, resetting the counter when starting the chapter will not produce any unexpected results.

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem and saved me from manual figures/tables counting throughout the thesis. I don't understand, however, why `totcount` developers would not impement such functionality.

Comment: This fails for me unless I build at least once without it and leave the .aux files. Anyway to make it work out of the box?

Comment: @mangledorf that is because the information is first written to the `.aux` file (on the first run) and then read from it (on the second run). The current implementation has this disadvantage; if I think of a work-around I'll let you know.

Comment: I found a solution, add `\providecommand{\totfig}{??}
\providecommand{\tottab}{??}` below the `\newcounter` commands

Comment: 1) How to count figures that are inserted in a `report` before any `\chapter{}`? 2) Can `\AtEndDocument` be included in my custom class definition?

Answer (score 7):

This appears to work for me:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
% http://texblog.org/2012/04/16/counting-the-total-number-of/
\usepackage{totcount}
\newtotcounter{citenum}
\def\oldcite{}
\let\oldcite=\bibcite
\def\bibcite{\stepcounter{citenum}\oldcite}

\usepackage[figure,table]{totalcount}
% different from totcount, and not on CTAN. Found at
% http://www.mrunix.de/forums/showpost.php?p=257537&postcount=10
% Reference: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=9028

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article {MCOSW,
author = "Hugh Glaser and Afraz Jafri and Ian Millard",
title = "Managing co-reference on the semantic web",
journal = "WWW2009 Workshop: Linked Data on the Web (LDOW2009)",
month = "April",
year = "April 2009",
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}

Some citations: \cite{MCOSW}, \cite{MCOSW}, \cite{MCOSW}.
This document contains \totalfigures{} figures, \totaltables{} tables, and
\total{citenum} reference (possibly with multiple citations).

\begin{table}
\caption{Table caption}
\centering Table content
\end{table}
\begin{figure}
\centering Figure content
\caption{Figure caption}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Two}

\begin{table}
\caption{Table caption}
\centering Table content
\end{table}
\begin{figure}
\centering Figure content
\caption{Figure caption}
\end{figure}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Uppps. This reminds me that I totally forgot to put totalcount on CTAN which was due four years ago. Will do with the next update of the caption package... (which will hopefully be done this year ;-))

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt I posted an answer using your wonderful package :)

Comment: I especially appreciate how easy it is to count customized counters with the totcount package. Thanks for the pointer! Most helpful for me was the Example section of https://ctan.space-pro.be/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/totcount/totcount.pdf

Answer (score 5):

The [`totalcount`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/totalcount) package handles this easily

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[figure,table]{totalcount}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
There are \totalfigures\ figures and \totaltables\ tables in this document.
\begin{figure}FA\caption{test FA}\end{figure}
\begin{table}TA\caption{test TA}\end{table}
\begin{figure}FB\caption{test FB}\end{figure}

\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\begin{figure}FC\caption{test FC}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}FD\caption{test FD}\end{figure}
\begin{table}TB\caption{test TB}\end{table}
\begin{figure}FE\caption{test FE}\end{figure}

\chapter{Test Chapter Three}
\begin{table}TC\caption{test TC}\end{table}
\begin{figure}FF\caption{test FF}\end{figure}
\begin{table}TD\caption{test TD}\end{table}

\end{document}
```