# Total number of citations

Tags: bibliographies, counters

I am trying find an easy way to get the total number of citations in my thesis (in the final document - not in my `Libary.bib` file!). I know that I can use `\citenum{last_entry}` to get the number of the last entry, but in case there is a new entry added later, this doesn't give me the total number of citations anymore. I found the package `\usepackage{totcount}` helpful, because it give you a super easy way to get the total number of figures, tables, etc.

My questions is: Is there a similar command for the total number of citations? I searched quite a bit, but didn't find anything helpful.

Just in case this info is needed - I use a numeric output such as:

[1] P. Drude, Physikal. Zeitschr. 1, 161 (1900)

Example of how I currently use the package totcount for the total number of figures, tables:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{totcount}
\newtotcounter{bibitems}
\newtotcounter{figure}
\regtotcounter{table}

\begin{document}
The total number of figures is \total{figure}, and the total number of tables is \total{table}.



\begin{figure}
[...]
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
[...]
\end{figure}



\begin{table}
[...]
\end{end}

\begin{table}
[...]
\end{end}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I assume references, say you refer three time to the same thing, does this count as one or as three?

Comment: have you seen [Count number of figures, tables and citations in report class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55580) and [Count number of references using biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66829), for example?

Answer (score 13):

You can do this using the [totcount package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/totcount).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{totcount}

\newtotcounter{citnum} %From the package documentation
\def\oldbibitem{} \let\oldbibitem=\bibitem
\def\bibitem{\stepcounter{citnum}\oldbibitem}

\begin{document}
This document contains \total{citnum}\ references.

\cite{Martin06} \cite{Fortran2008}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{Martin06}
P.~A. Martin.
\newblock {\em Multiple Scattering. {Interaction} of Time-Harmonic Waves with
  {$N$} Obstacles}.
\newblock Cambridge University Press, 2006.

\bibitem{Fortran2008}
Fortran standards technical~committee (J3).
\newblock Fortran 2008 language standard.
\newblock Technical Report J3/10-007, International Committee for Information
  Technology Standards (INCITS), 2010.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Note that this works for bibtex bibliographies as well; I included the bibliography environment to make the example as simple as possible.

Comment: Does this work for a BibTeX bibliography as well?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. --- Yes. I just included the bibliography environment to make the example as simple as possible. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Aha! @IanThompson I was a that point already. But the number returned was always "0". Turned out that I adding \newtotcounter{citnum} etc. to the style file is not a good idea! Added to the header works great! Thx though!

Comment: + 1: the perfect solution!

Answer (score 12):

an alternative with biblatex for simply counting the number of entries in a bibliography is to use `\AtEveryBibitem`.

```
\usepackage{totcount}
\newtotcounter{citenum}
\AtEveryBibitem{\stepcounter{citenum}}
```

for multiple `\printbibliography` calls the counter can be reset with `\AtNextBibliography`.

Comment: I included this to my preamble, but I cannot find the place where the number of citations is given. Is it in the bibliography itself?

Answer (score 6):

If you are allowed to perform a `shell-escape`, when LaTeX uses bibliography, a `<your_document_name>.blg` file is produced (remember to replace `<your_document_name>` with the name of your real file). In this file the following line appears:

```
...
You've used 8 entries,
...
```

So you can run

```
grep -P "You've used [0-9]+ entries," -m 1 "<your_document_name>.blg" | grep -P "[0-9]+" -o
```

By using the following document, this number will be printed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bashful}
\begin{document}
Foo...

\bash[script,stdout]
grep -P "You've used [0-9]+ entries," -m 1 "<your_document_name>.blg" | grep -P "[0-9]+" -o
\END
\end{document}
```

**Please note**: you must eplace `<your_document_name>` with the right name of your file.