# Count number of publications with a specific first author

Tags: bibtex, cv

I am trying to make a more automatic latex CV.  I'd like my reference section to lead with: "Refereed Publications (N first author, M total):"

For the M total, I have found a solution based on [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163451/total-number-of-citations):

```
\usepackage{totcount}

\newtotcounter{citnum} %From the package documentation
\def\oldbibitem{} \let\oldbibitem=\bibitem
\def\bibitem{\stepcounter{citnum}\oldbibitem}

\renewcommand{\refname}{Refereed Publications [N first author, \total{citnum} total]:}
```

This results in the heading for the `Bibliography` section being changed to `Refereed Publications [9 first author, 45 total]:`, where the number `9` in this example is hard-coded and the number `45` has been counted by latex.

How can I do the same sort of counting, but only for the N publications on which I am the first author?

MWE added as per Johannes_B's request:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{totcount}

\newtotcounter{citnum} %From the package documentation
\def\oldbibitem{} \let\oldbibitem=\bibitem
\def\bibitem{\stepcounter{citnum}\oldbibitem}

\renewcommand{\refname}{Refereed Publications [2 first author, \total{citnum} total]:}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{apj_revchron}
\bibliography{mwe}
\end{document}
```

With the bib file `mwe.bib`:

```
@article{one,
    author = {{me}, a. and {you}, b.},
    title = {one},
    journal = {one},
    year = {2015},
}
@article{two,
    author = {{you}, a. and {me}, b.},
    title = {two},
    journal = {two},
    year = {2015},
}
@article{three,
    author = {{me}, a. and {you}, b. and {them}},
    title = {three},
    journal = {three},
    year = {2015},
}
```

This will result in the heading:
`Refereed Publications [2 first author, 3 total]:`
My question is, how can the `2` here be automatically determined?

Comment: Hi there, i really don't understand what you want. Can you extend the question/explanation and add a working example?

Comment: Johannes_B: I want to count the number of publications cited that have a specific first author.   Counting the *total* number of cited publications is demonstrated in the example.

Comment: "Can you extend the question/explanation and add a working example?" The question is that big thing above your picture, not a comment.

Comment: I cannot add a working example - I do not know how to implement this.  I'll extend the question, though.

Comment: A minimal working example lets us reproduce what you are trying. Are you using natbib? jurabib? biblatex? cite? any package at all?

Comment: Johannes_B: natbib.  A complete MWE is now included in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33910/discussion-between-keflavich-and-johannes-b).

Answer (score 5):

Here a solution mostly stolen from [Audrey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4483/audrey) in [Count number of references using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66829/count-number-of-references-using-biblatex/66868#66868)

[image: keflavichCountCites]

```
%\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{one,
        author = {Bee, B. and Wombat, W.},
        title = {Loving cobblestone},
        journal = {Stones weekly},
        year = {2015},
        keywords = {mefirst},
    }
    @article{two,
        author = {Wombat, W. and Bee, B.},
        title = {Flying Penguins},
        journal = {MP Monthly},
        year = {2015},
    }
    @article{three,
        author = {Bee, Busy and Wombat, Walzing and Penguins},
        title = {Animal Friendships},
        journal = {Madagascar Quarterly},
        year = {2015},
        keywords = {mefirst},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\defbibheading{bibliography}[]{\section*{Refereed Publications}
\arabic{firstA} as first author, a total of \arabic{sum}\medbreak
}
\newcounter{firstA}
\newcounter{notfirst}
\AtDataInput{%
    \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifkeyword{mefirst}} }
    { \stepcounter{firstA} }
    { \stepcounter{notfirst} }%
}
\newcounter{sum}

\begin{document}
\defcounter{sum}{\value{firstA}+\value{notfirst}}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: This requires biblatex, right?  I am using natbib.  It seems that either natbib and biblatex are incompatible and/or my style file is incompatible with biblatex.

Comment: @keflavich Yes, `biblatex` replaces `natbib` and the `bst` files you are having. Since you `bst` looks like a usual numeric style, i didn't bother. Personally, i don't use `BibTex` and related packages, because making changes is a pure pain (as already mentioned).

Comment: I get errors `I found no \citation commands` and no `\bibdata`, `\bibstyle` when I run your example.  Is there something missing?

Comment: You need to run biber. [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154767)

Comment: It looks like this approach works if I use biblatex & biber, but that is not an option for me at present since I already have a painstakingly customized .bst file and no time to develop a corresponding style file for biblatex.  If it is impossible to do what I want with bibtex, then I'll eventually accept this answer, but I am hoping for a solution that uses bibtex.

Comment: @keflavich First thing i would do, is draw attention to the questioin by tagging it correctly. What does that have to do with resumes? Nothing.