# How to call \printbibliography and \section only if there are sources cited

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I'm working on many papers with a few header files that do important stuff (define functions etc.). I'd like to create a new "header" (or: "footer") file that contains this:

```
\clearpage
\section{Sources}
\printbibliography
\clearpage
```

But some of these documents have no sources cited and there's an empty page added then.

Is there any way to do this?

```
\if(numberOfUsedSources > 1) {
    \clearpage
    \section{Sources}
    \printbibliography
    \clearpage
}
```

It would be really helpful!

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163451/total-number-of-citations, combine with, e.g., the `ifnum` example in the `totcount` documentation (Section 6).

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={Sources}]`.
This should only print anything if there are cited entries, and will add a section titled "Sources" in that case.
In case the documentclass uses chapters (e.g., `book`) you should use `subbibintoc` instead.

As, lacking a MWE, we don't know more details of your overall settings, I can only guess that, probably, the `clearpage`s can be handled without the conditional, given the appearing/non appearing bibliography.

**Update**: Somewhat more elaborate, and handling the `\clearpage`s as well. In full:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\defbibheading{myheading}[Sources]{%
    \clearpage%
    \section{#1}}

\defbibnote{mypostnote}{\clearpage}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\kant[1-4]

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=myheading,postnote=mypostnote]

\kant[1-4]

\newrefsection
\section{Section 2}

\kant[1-4]

\printbibliography[heading=myheading,postnote=mypostnote]

\kant[1-4]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

When asking a question it's always good to include a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) so that people know what `\documentclass` etc you are using. A MWE also makes it easier to answer your question as it frequently helps clarify what the issues are-- and it gives people working code to start from.

There may be a standard [biblatex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) way of doing this but, failing that, I suggest creating a new boolean, say `\ifCiting`, and then redefining `\cite` so that it first sets `\Citingtrue` and then uses the real `\cite` command. You can then use `\ifCiting...\fi` to print your bibliography section, or not.

Here's one way to do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\let\realCite\cite% save the orginal \cite macro as \realCite for future use
\newif\ifCiting\Citingfalse% no citations by default
\renewcommand\cite[2][]{% optional argument is empty by default
  \Citingtrue% we have at least one citation!
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax% no optional argument
    \realCite{#2}%
  \else% an optional argument
    \realCite[#1]{#2}%
  \fi%
}

\begin{document}

\ifCiting
    \clearpage
    \section{Sources}
    \printbibliography
    \clearpage
\fi

\end{document}
```

This only tricky bit is in checking to see whether or not the optional argument to `\cite` is "empty". The standard way of doing this is the line `\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax`.

**Edit**

As Skillmon pointed out in the comments, a much more efficient (and "globally" correct) solution is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\let\realCite\cite% save the orginal \cite macro for future use
\newif\ifCiting\Citingfalse% no citations by default
\renewcommand*\cite{\global\Citingtrue\realCite}

\begin{document}

\ifCiting
    \clearpage
    \section{Sources}
    \printbibliography
    \clearpage
\fi

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not use something like: `\let\realCite\cite\renewcommand*\cite{\global\Citingtrue\realCite}`?

Comment: @Skillmon Yes, that's much better on two counts - the addition of `\global` and much more succinct! I'll edit.

Comment: The only thing I'm not sure about atm is, whether to use `\let` or `\LetLtxMacro`.

Comment: @Skillmon In this instance, `\let` seems to work fine.