# How to get a total number of literature references and save it to a user defined counter?

Tags: counters, zref, xr, refcount, totcount

During my last experience with Cross-referencing on total counts between different files, which can be read [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/337263/44348), a problem of saving the total number of literature references in a user defined counter appears.

There are at least two ways to save this value in auxiliary file using:

1. `zref` package given by Heiko Oberdiek, see, please, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/337344/44348)
2. `xr` and `refcount` packages given by Werner, see, please, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129317/44348)

There are at least two ways of forming total count of literature references using:

1. `totcount` package given by Mike Renfro and also by Ian Thompson, see, please, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55585/44348) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163455/44348), respectively.
2. `\printbibliography`makro given by Maieul, see, please, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66851/44348). However in this case we produce also bibliographies of difference types.

I try to get a total count of literature references by `totcount` and save it by `zref`. The problem is that command `\total{citenum}` returns a dirty code, e.g. `\def \c@citenum@totc {\c@citenum@totc }2}` for MWE, so I can not export this value to another .tex file. Note, that the last value `2` is a true value of references mentioned in a source code.

The question is how get a total number of literature references and save it to a user defined counter in a correct way? A given value should be compatible with one of the approaches to export the value to another .tex file.

The simplest way to solve the problem is to parse the following line `\def \c@citenum@totc {\c@citenum@totc }2}` and save symbols between last `}` and `}` in a separate counter. There can be also approaches to hack `totcount` or use another packages to form a total count of literature references.

MWE is a combination of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/337344/44348) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163455/44348) MWEs.

```
    \documentclass{report}
    % http://texblog.org/2012/04/16/counting-the-total-number-of/
    \usepackage{totcount}
    \newtotcounter{citenum}
    \def\oldcite{}
    \let\oldcite=\bibcite
    \def\bibcite{\stepcounter{citenum}\oldcite}


    \usepackage{zref-abspage, zref-lastpage}
    \makeatletter
    \zref@newprop{myreferences}[0]{\total{citenum}}
    \zref@addprops{LastPage}{myreferences}
    \makeatother



    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article {First,
    author = "FA"
    }
    @article {Second,
        author = "SA"
    }
    \end{filecontents}

    \begin{document}


    Some citations: \cite{First}, \cite{First}, \cite{Second}.
    This document contains \total{citenum} references (possibly with multiple citations).

    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{\jobname}

    \end{document}
```

A screenshot from an auxiliary file with highlighted part of text, which should be correct, i.e. there should be only value `2`.

[image: wrong format of total count of literature references]

UPT: I've tried to modify Werner's [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129317/44348), i.e. put `\total{citenum}` in the following code `\setcounter{mycntr}{\total{citenum}}` and got the error: `Missing number, treated as zero. \setcounter{mycntr}{\total{citenum}}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
   \zref@newprop{myreferences}[0]{\total{citenum}}
```

with

```
   \zref@newprop{myreferences}[0]{\the\totvalue{citenum}}
```

Comment: @ Piet van Oostum, thank you for this hint. It seems to work also with Werner's approach. How did you manage to find a solution? For example, how to name a counter with total citings with, which is generated by very similar command `\citesnum` from p.2 of [totcount package}(http://ctan.altspu.ru/macros/latex/contrib/totcount/totcount.pdf)? `\the\totvalue{citesnum}`?

Comment: Well, the totcount package doc gives \totalcount for printing the total, and \totvalue for the numerical value. So I first used \totvalue, and looked in the .aux file. I saw the name of the counter there. Then \the is the logical step to get the actual value.