# Execute command \AtEndDocument in a custom class

Tags: document-classes

I am studying [Count number of figures, tables and citations in report class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55580/count-number-of-figures-tables-and-citations-in-report-class?answertab=active#tab-top). I am writing a custom class that would have this implementation built in. I would like to move the commands `\AtEndDocument` from the preamble to the `.cls` file. The problem is that they do not get executed in case of a simple copy.
Can you help?

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: Mhhh, `\AtEndDocument` should just work in a `.cls` file. It certainly worked for me in a short example I just wrote. It would be much easier to answer this question if you could show us an example document and an example `.cls` file of what you tried, what you expected and how it failed for you.

Comment: @moewe, could it be that I provided `\AtEndDocument` after `\endinput`?

Comment: Well yes, that would definitely be a problem. Everything after `\endinput` is ignored.

Comment: that is why questions should always have example code, the cause of the problem isn't mentioned in the question.  tex does not read the text at all on any lines after `\endinput`